# Proving $n \log n \in O(n^{1+\epsilon})$ without limits

Tags: asymptotics

How can one show that $n \log n \in O(n^{1+\epsilon})$ where $0 < \epsilon < 1$ without using limits? This question arise from a homework where I used limits to prove the relation. I'd like to know if there is another way.

Comment: A bit nitpicky:  I suggest either saying $\epsilon$ is fixed, or writing the above as $n\log n=O_\epsilon \left(n^{1+\epsilon}\right)$ to indicate the constant depends on $\epsilon$.  (Otherwise it is simply not true)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $0<\epsilon<1$ be fixed. We need only show that $\log n=O(n^\epsilon)$. Suppose $n\geq 1$ so that $\log n\geq 0$.  Since $$n^\epsilon=e^{\epsilon \log n}=1+\epsilon \log n+\frac{\epsilon^2 \log^2 n}{2}\cdots \geq \epsilon \log n$$ we see that $$\log n \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon}n^\epsilon $$ which proves the desired result.

Comment: Why couldn't you stop the expansion at $\epsilon \log n$?

Comment: @Pho:  Huh.  You could!  Great idea.  I edited accordingly.

Comment: Instead of expanding into a series you could use the inequality $e^x \geq 1+x$.